# Introduction to analysis: recommended things to understand

Tags: analysis, reference-request

I'm beginning my analysis class next semester and was wondering what should I be very familiar with. For example, in the first page of "Principles of mathematical anylysis" by Walter Rudin, he starts by saying "we assume familiarity with the rational numbers". I mean I'm somewhat familiar with them but only did a discrete math class so we stopped at integers. So, what would be the things I should do to be really prepared for an introduction to analysis class?

Thank you!

Comment: Try working through the first chapter on your own. That will alert you to expected prerequisite knowledge.